# In junit4 is there a way to create a data driven test with multiple types like int, double, and string?

Tags: java, junit4

I am writing a test in junit 4 to test multiple data types. How would I get the data driven test to run as int, double, and String when testing the method when the method cannot take an Object type in.

```
Object[][] data = {
            {1, 2, 3, 1},
            {3, 1, 2, 1},
            {0, 0, 0, 0},
            {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0},
            {-1.0, -2.0, -3.0, -3.0},
            {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
            {"a", "b", "c"},
            {"hi", "bye", "hello"},
            {"boy", "girl", "child"}
        };
```

I tried creating the data driven tests seperately, but that does not work as there is only one a, b, c variable. After this I tried creating serparate variables but that requires more than one constructor which is not possible.

Comment: What your unit test looks like?

Comment: @HarryCoder Test
    public void testMinInt() {
        ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(a);
        list.add(b);
        list.add(c);
        assertEquals(expected, Min.min(list));
    } //This test finds the min of each test set but will not take in list for Min.min

Comment: Please put the test code into the question (formatted as a code block) rather than a comment, where it is difficult to read.

Comment: And also please include the code being tested (the `Min.min` implementation).

Comment: @sbadl update your code.